# How do I make Jenkins's pipeline, Maven's scm:tag, and Git LFS play nicely together?

Tags: git, maven, jenkins

I've got a Jenkinsfile build of a Java/Maven project that's failing with the following error:

```
[INFO] --- maven-scm-plugin:1.9.4:tag (default-cli) @ bluebutton-data-pipeline ---
[INFO] Final Tag Name: 'bluebutton-data-pipeline-0.1.0-23'
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/HHSIDEAlab/bluebutton-data-pipeline/master && git tag -F /tmp/maven-scm-1982238691.commit bluebutton-data-pipeline-0.1.0-23
[INFO] Working directory: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/HHSIDEAlab/bluebutton-data-pipeline/master
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/HHSIDEAlab/bluebutton-data-pipeline/master && git push git@github.com:HHSIDEAlab/bluebutton-data-pipeline.git refs/tags/bluebutton-data-pipeline-0.1.0-23
[INFO] Working directory: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/HHSIDEAlab/bluebutton-data-pipeline/master
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The git-push command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] Git credentials for https://github.com/HHSIDEAlab/bluebutton-data-pipeline.git/info/lfs/objects not found.
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:HHSIDEAlab/bluebutton-data-pipeline.git'
```

The job at issue is a "Multibranch Pipeline" job in Jenkins, and has credentials for a personal access token. This works just fine for the non-LFS jobs, and only fails in the LFS job for the `scm:tag` goal.

Not entirely sure how to resolve this, or even which component to file a ticket against. It appears that Git LFS is expecting credentials to come in via Git's [gitcredentials](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials) system, but Jenkins doesn't seem to support that.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I hacked around this for the time being by manually configuring Git to use the "store" credentials helper (via `git config credential.helper store`), and then creating a `/var/lib/jenkins/.git-credentials` file with the repo's LFS credentials. Ugly, but it works for now.

Comment: I also found this Jenkins plugin issue, which indicates that perhaps this won't work for new jobs/branches: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-30318